# How do I get a variable from my main window to use in my child window?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a program that will take integer input from a main window and if the user selects "no" in the child window, I want to take those inputs from the main window and calculate some values in my child window.

I tried calling the restemp and respres in the main window and then use it in the child window but it says Ui_Sgselect(), the class in child window, cannot take any arguments

The first part of the main window:

```
class Ui_DryGasProperties(object):
    def afterselect1(self):
        #this function opens up the child window after hitting select in the main window

        if self.Firstselect.currentText() == 'Specific Gravity':
            self.Tp = self.Restemp.text() 
            self.Pp = self.respres.text()
            #Restemp and Respres are the integer user inputs I want to use
            self.ui = Ui_Sgselect() #Sgselect is the new window class
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
```

The child window looks like this:

```
class Ui_Sgselect(object):

    def secondselect(self): 
        #the function when submit is clicked in the child window
        if self.Nonhydrselect.currentText() == 'Yes':
            self.ui = Ui_Afternonhydr() #other windows that open afterwards
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()

        elif self.Nonhydrselect.currentText() == "I don't know":
            self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
            self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()

        elif self.Nonhydrselect.currentText() == 'No':

          #this is where the value from main window has to be used
            sg1 = float(self.SG.text())
            Tpc = 168 + (325 * sg1) - (12.5 * (sg1 ** 2))  

            Ppc = 677 + (15 * sg1) - (37.5 * (sg1 ** 2))

                #Tp1 = float(self.Tp)
                #Pp1 = float(self.Pp)
                #Tpr = (Tp1 + 460) / Tpc
                #Ppr = Pp1 / Ppc
                #Tpr1 = round(Tpr, 2)
                #Ppr1 = round(Ppr, 2)
            print(Tpr)
            print(Ppr)
```

Extremely new to programming. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically pass a handle from the parent window `self.child = childWindow(self)` to the child window class `childWindow(self, parent)` note this is just semi-pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly change your class structure so that when you update your UI's it does not change your methods or you accidentally delete them.

So the code you get from QtDesigner, just leave it alone and make another class inherting the Ui as shown below.

You can pass the window as an argument to the Sgselect class where it is being initalized.

This is assuming all of the Ui's are in the same module.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets
#ui for all windows go between here
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class Afternonhydr(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_Afternonhydr):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class DryGasProperties(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_DryGasProperties)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def afterselect1(self):
        if self.Firstselect.currentText() == 'Specific Gravity':
            self.Tp = self.Restemp.text() 
            self.Pp = self.respres.text()
            self.SgselectWindow = Sgselect(self)
            self.SgselectWindow.show()

class Sgselect(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_Sgselect):
    def __init__(self,window,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Tp = window.Tp
        self.Pp = window.Pp

    def secondselect(self): 
        #the function when submit is clicked in the child window
        if self.Nonhydrselect.currentText() == 'Yes':
            self.afternonhydrWindow = Afternonhydr()
            self.afternonhydrWindow.show()

        elif self.Nonhydrselect.currentText() == "I don't know":
            self.dialogWindow = Dialog()
            self.dialogWindow.show()

        elif self.Nonhydrselect.currentText() == 'No':
            sg1 = float(self.SG.text())
            Tpc = 168 + (325 * sg1) - (12.5 * (sg1 ** 2))  

            Ppc = 677 + (15 * sg1) - (37.5 * (sg1 ** 2))

                Tp1 = float(self.Tp)
                Pp1 = float(self.Pp)
                Tpr = (Tp1 + 460) / Tpc
                Ppr = Pp1 / Ppc
                Tpr1 = round(Tpr, 2)
                Ppr1 = round(Ppr, 2)
            print(Tpr)
            print(Ppr)
```

or instead of passing the entire window as a parameter you can just specify the items you want sent to the other window. For example,

Change the parts of your code in `class Sgselect` to the following;

`self.SgselectWindow = Sgselect(self.Tp,self.Pp)`

and

```
    def __init__(self,Tp,Pp,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Tp = Tp
        self.Pp = Pp
```

To have the different ui’s in different modules  just add them in different py files and import them at the top as such `from [insert py file name here] import [ui class name]`